# switch tabs programmatically in xamDockManager

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I have few tabs like Photo,Story,Graphics inside XamDockManager.I need to select a tab on the basis of shortcut key press like(ALT+CTRl+S for story).I am able to capture these shortcut key press event by using RoutedUICommand but i am kinda stucked at selecting the particular tab programatically.Please help me how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Infragistic Docs may help you http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by calling Activate method of the ContentPane.

Answer (score 0):

Give the TabControl a Name

```
<igWindows:XamTabControl x:Name="myTabControl">
```

And set the tab via SelectedItem in your code:

```
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  //if ALT+CTRL+S...
  myTabControl.SelectedItem = myTabControl.Items[0];
}
```

Comment: Strange just tested it out with 11.2 and it works fine for me :(